# While loop for creating multiple resources with capacity

Tags: r, event-simulation

I need to create 52 resources with capacity 2 in the Simmer simulation package. I am trying to do this by using a while loop that creates these resources for me, instead of creating each resource myself.
The idea is that I have a while loop as given below. In each loop, a resource should be created called Transport_vehicle1, Transport_vehicle2, ..., Transport_vehicle52, with capacity 2.

Now I do not know how to insert the number i in the name of the resource that I am trying to create

```
i<-1
while (i<=52)
{ env %>%
  add_resource("Transport_vehicle"[i],capacity = 2)
  i <- i+1
}
```

Could someone please help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`paste`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.1/topics/paste) method to concatenate the string and the number:

```
i<-1
while (i<=52)
{ env %>%
  add_resource(paste("Transport_vehicle", i),capacity = 2)
  i <- i+1
}
```

If you do not want a space between the string and the number add the `sep=""` argument

```
paste("Transport_vehicle", i, sep="")
```

or use

```
paste0("Transport_vehicle", i)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it

Comment: @DaanvandeVen if that's your answer, you should give credit by accepting it.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest a for loop instead: `for (i in 1:52) ...`.